# Get dynamic Value of input JQuery + Twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I am trying to get a value from a hidden input with dynamic value:

```
<form>
    <input class="AAA" type="hidden" value="{{ categorie.idcategorie }}" >
        <a type="submit" name="clickdelete" class="clickdelete">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Supprimer Categorie</a>  
</form>
```

As you can see this an hidden input value with dynamic value which is an ID that am going to use in my script to send an AJAX request.

I tried this :

```
var id = $(".AAA").attr("value");
console.log( id )
```

and also like this :

```
console.log( $(".AAA").val()  )
```

Whatever element I select, I always get the first value which is `1`

Now if I try to debug it and change `input` type into `text` I get different values on each element witch is good but how to get values on my script?

Comment: Target the ID, not the class.

Comment: what is wrong with targeting class if class is only used once it would work

Comment: thanks for answering  i've already change it  and  always the same result

Comment: What do you mean by `Whatever element i select i always get the first value which is 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, instead to use a hidden input, you could use the attribute 'data' in Links, in this case will be named: data-delete:

https://jsfiddle.net/kaLeokgt/

```
<form> 
<a href="#" class="clickdelete" data-delete="1"> 
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Supprimer Categorie
</a>
<br>

<a href="#" class="clickdelete" data-delete="2"> 
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Supprimer Categorie
</a>

</form>
```

Now, get dynamically the attribute value:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickdelete').click(function () {        
        var id = $(this).attr('data-delete');
        alert(id);
    });

});
</script>
```

You will get  the value '1' or '2', according the link that you have clicked, of course you have to replace that numbers with {{ categorie.idcategorie }}